# CodeIgniter URI strange behaviour

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri

I have a strange encoutner with CI's routes

```
$route['pc/r/ios/total/(:any)'] = "pc/usr/ios/overall/5";
$route['pc/r/ios/total/(:any)'] = "pc/usr/ios/overall/$1";
```

this one doesn't work

```
$route['pc/r/ios/total/5'] = "pc/usr/ios/overall/5";
```

this one works!

```
$route['u/a/(:any)'] = "pc/usr/main_controller/game_detail/$1";
```

this one works!

so I wonder why the first one doesn't work..

any ideas please? thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may have some thing like

```
//$route['pc/(:any)'] = "pc/$1";
//$route['pc/(:any)/(:any)'] = "pc/$1/$2";
```

please check!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing in the variable:

```
$route['pc/r/ios/total/(:any)'] = "pc/usr/ios/overall/5";
```

...should be:

```
$route['pc/r/ios/total/(:any)'] = "pc/usr/ios/overall/$1";
```

Comment: doesn't work = 404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.


and 


works = "page successfully loaded everything"

Comment: Try now. I swapped out the double quotation marks for single ones.

Comment: seems weird 

I tried 
replacing one by one and then 
$route['pc/r/ios/total/(:any)'] = "pc/usr/ios/overall/$1";
this one worked correctly... weird

Comment: nope the original one.. the one I posted as not working..

I tried changing each uri one by one

Comment: Ok, Im confused and tired. I'm going to go to sleep now. good luck!

Comment: thanks! 
FYI
//$route['pc/(:any)'] = "pc/$1";
//$route['pc/(:any)/(:any)'] = "pc/$1/$2";
I deleteed these codes

Comment: Oh, well damn. I thought you wanted to use more levels in the URL. Of course the default CI method is going to work. :O